# Como buscar varias palavras simultâneas no arquivo.txt, so consigo com uma unica palavra

Tags: python

```
ArquivoEntrada = "Arquivo.txt"
ArquivoSaida = "Arquivoextraidolinhas.txt"
 
Buscando = "Fica"


with open(ArquivoSaida, 'w', encoding='UTF-8', ) as saida:
    with open(ArquivoEntrada, "r", encoding='UTF-8') as entrada:
        for words in entrada:            
            if Buscando in words:                        
                    saida.write(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi o objetivo do seu código é:

- dada uma lista de palavras
- dado um arquivo de entrada
- escrever em um arquivo de saída as palavras que constam tanto na lista quanto no arquivo de entrada.

A primeira observação é que a que a expressão:

```
for words in entrada:
```

O que vai ser iterado na variável *words* serão as linhas.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de código que faz o comparativo que deseja.
Basta adaptá-lo para escrever os resultados no arquivo de saída.

arquivo.txt

```
Essa é a primeira linha de um arquivo txt.
Essa é a segunda linha de um arquivo txt.
```

Código:

```
arquivo_entrada = "arquivo.txt"
lista_palavras = ['primeira','segunda']

with open(arquivo_entrada, "r", encoding='UTF-8') as entrada:
    linhas_entrada = entrada.readlines()

for linha in linhas_entrada:
    for palavra in lista_palavras:
        if palavra in linha:
            print(palavra, ' - ', linha)
```